# Pros and Cons of loading content for a welcome stream from a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

This may get flagged as it's opinion based, but I want to see what the experts think.

We are about to build a Welcome Stream and I can do it one of two ways.

The first way is to build it all as HTML and set up my Journey in Journey Builder. Pretty straightforward.

The second is to build my emails with HTML and AMPScript that calls data extensions to load the content. It should be fairly simple because 10 emails could likely call one data extension, look for it's own filename, and grab the content it needs. I see the pros in this. Easy to update and I don't have to restart the triggered send if we want to update the content. But does anyone see cons with this approach?